# Why is HTTP/s disallowed in an Azure B2C native redirect URI?

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I'd like to only use Universal Links back to my application, and not have to worry about other apps "hijacking" my app URI.

Now that I'm trying to integrate Azure B2c into my native client, I wonder why B2C requires that I specify a custom uri such as `myapp://` as a redirect.

[image]

Questions:

- Why is HTTP/S disabled on B2C? What risks or features are they concerned about?
- If I use a non-universal link on my application, and a malicious app reuses that identifier (`myapp://`) what are the risks I need to look out for?

I'm adding tags for the on-app multi factor (Phonefactor?) in case that is partially the reason why it's not supported. (in any event, could I not simply redirect back to that app in my native client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this is not ideal and you can upvote the feature request here so that the product team prioritizes this release. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19688731-support-azure-ad-native-app-flow-in-azure-ad-b2c

App-claimed "https" scheme redirect URIs have some advantages compared to other native app redirect options in that the identity of the destination app is guaranteed to the authorization server by the operating system. For this reason, native apps should use them over the other options where possible.The Web Platform also claims the client_secret which induces security problems and is discouraged on Native Applications.

For now you'll have to do it with the custom URL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app

Comment: Thank you for this! What is the Web Platform and the relation to client secret security issue?

Comment: You need to use a web platform in order to use http or https.